# Uploaded images are not stored in file folder in Opencart 2.0

Tags: image, file, file-upload, opencart

When i upload images of product in opencart, reference of image files are stored in db but actual image file are not stored in folders, and only alternative text is displayed both in thumbnail page as well as in Product page.

Comment: Check image upload path in config.php in your project. May be path is not specified properly.

Comment: most likely, the web-server doesn't have permission to write there ...

Comment: image path file is correct, getting error only if we upload new images

Comment: I found one issue, when we upload image it is stored under image/catalog folder, but not stored under image/cache/catalog folder. in front end images are picked from image/cache/catalog. So what images not displayed either while uploading as well as in front end. Also provided 777 permission for all folder under images folders. Anyone help me in this ?

Comment: Images are stored in  image/catalog folder but why it is rendered from Image/cache/catalog folder in all places, if that is the case uploaded images are not stored in Image/cache/catalog. Please clarify my doubt